# How to resize a char array of unique pointer belonging to a class. It must be kept alive for the whole life of the program

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, unique-ptr

I have a class called container containing a std::unique_ptr _ptr.
This _ptr must be kept alive for the whole process of the program. I cannot lose it. When Finally the container object is destroyed. It will be destroyed along with it.

At some part of the program. I need to add a character to _ptr array. For this purpouse I use the following function:

```
void resizeUniquePtrArray(std::unique_ptr<char[]> &ptr) {
   std::unique_ptr<char[]> newptr(new char[strlen(ptr.get())+2]);
  memcpy(newptr.get(), ptr.get(),strlen(ptr.get()));
  newptr[strlen(newptr.get())]= 'X';
  newptr[strlen(newptr.get()) + 1]= '\0';
  ptr = std::move(newptr);
}
```

## Constraints

I'm pretty sure I am doing something wrong. In my project Sometimes I lose the content of _ptr and sometimes I don't. The funny part is that valgrind gave no warnings.

- I can't use a string instead of std::unique_ptr because i'll have to use later on const_cast it's like raping the string that I created.
- I tried using vector and assignt it to char * by .data(). But Valgrind Went nuts and gave me all sort of read and write errors
- The problem is the C library with its char* rawPointer. It's really hard to go around it. I can't just use new char. Because i will have to carry it with me through all the program.

## Question

Is the resizing of the Char unique pointer array _ptr done correctly?

## Source Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory> 
#include <string.h>

class Container {
    public:
     Container(const std::string &data):_data(data),_ptr(new char[data.size() + 1]) {}

     std::unique_ptr<char[]> & initPtr(){
         strcpy(_ptr.get(),_data.c_str());
         _ptr[strlen(_ptr.get()) + 1] = '\0';
         return _ptr;
     }
     private:
       std::unique_ptr<char[]> _ptr;
       std::string _data;
};

void resizeUniquePtrArray(std::unique_ptr<char[]> &ptr) {
   std::unique_ptr<char[]> newptr(new char[strlen(ptr.get())+2]);
  memcpy(newptr.get(), ptr.get(),strlen(ptr.get()));
  newptr[strlen(newptr.get())]= 'X';
  newptr[strlen(newptr.get()) + 1]= '\0';
  ptr = std::move(newptr);
}

int main()
{
  std::string name = "hello";
  Container c(name);
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> &ptr = c.initPtr();
  resizeUniquePtrArray(ptr);

  char* rawPointer = ptr.get();
  std::cout<< rawPointer << std::endl;

  //API LIBRARY CALL TO rawPointer it's a looonng process

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason you have `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` instead of e.g. a `std::vector`?

Comment: I used a char std::vector. Take the code and put vector<char> I just switched unique_ptr with vector. And Valgrind gave me errors related to the destructor of the pointer.

I don't know what's going in the API. It's a very old one.

Comment: If you had a `std::vector` then there shouldn't be a pointer to destroy. How come you had both? Can you post the code you used with a `std::vector<char>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't use a `std::string` instead of `std::unique_ptr` because i'll have to use later on `const_cast` it's like raping the string that I created.

No `const_cast` is necessary to get a plain pointer to the underlying C-string:

```
std::string s("abc");
char* p = &s[0];
```

Or, in C++17:

```
char* q = s.data();
```